# Rearrange 8 columns in a text file with hundreds using awk or other

Tags: bash, awk, cut

Hoping this is an easy one.

I have a text file with hundreds of columns.  Just need to copy 8 of them (not in a row), move them to the 5th, 6th, 7th...columns, and then have the rest of the file after that as before.

I really don't want to write out an awk or cut command with 356 column place holders.

Thanks!

UPDATE - EXAMPLE:

```
A   B   C   D  E  F  G  ...  X  Y  Z
```

What I want is:

```
A   Y   K   L   Z   J   B   C   D   E   F   G   ...   X   Y   Z
```

Thank you for your help.

Oh and those letters actually represent whole columns separated by tabs.

Comment: What separates the "columns"? Post some SMALL and REPRESENTATIVE sample input and expected output.

Comment: If you don't specify the column numbers (duh!) and the column separators (needed for FS= param), you will not get good answers. assuming normal FS and the columns are 1,99,100 then `$1="$1 $99 $100"; $99=""; $100="";print` but fix the question please

Comment: Do you like to move `move them to the 5th, 6th, 7th` or copy `Just need to copy 8 of them` the data?  For me it would be some confusing to have the same data in different columns.

Answer (score 0):

Some like this?

```
awk '{$5=$70;$6=$35;$7=$122;$8=$190;$9=$55;$10=$200;$11=$12;$12=$67}1' file
```

EDIT:
This moves certain columns to position 6 to 8 and then delete original position.

```
cat file
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
    awk '{a[++i]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<=5;i++) printf "%s ",a[i];printf "%s %s %s ",a[16],a[8],a[22];a[16]=a[8]=a[22]="";for (i=6;i<=27;i++) printf "%s ",a[i]}' RS="[ \t]" file | awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\t"

    A       B       C       D       E       P       H       V       F       G       I       J       K       L       M       N       O       Q       R       S       T       U       W       X       Y       Z
```

EDIT2: a some more clean version

```
awk '
    {
    a[++i]=$0
    } 
END {
    for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
        printf "%s\t",a[i]
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t",a[16],a[8],a[22]
    a[16]=a[8]=a[22]=""
    for (i=6;i<=27;i++)
        if (a[i])
            printf "%s\t",a[i]
    }
    ' RS="[[:space:]]" file
```

EDIT3: If you `awk` does not support this type of `RS`, use this solution

```
awk '
    {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        a[i]=$i
    } 
END {
    for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
        printf "%s\t",a[i]
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t",a[16],a[8],a[22]
    a[16]=a[8]=a[22]=""
    for (i=6;i<=27;i++)
        if (a[i])
            printf "%s\t",a[i]
    }
    ' file
```

Comment: First - thanks!  Actually, I need something that will copy and insert those columns in a different place not replace the other columns that are there.  Also - when I tried this - it took out all my tabs.

Comment: Add `OFS="\t"` to get tab.  You say you like them to 5,6,7.. position, but your example is now 2 and 5?

Comment: Thanks for the OFS="\t"!  Didn't mean to confuse.  Ultimately, I want to take columns 116, 119, 121, 124, 127, 129, 131, 134, 137, 140, 143, 146, 149, 152, 155, 158 and move them in between columns 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107983/rearrange-8-columns-in-a-text-file-with-hundreds-using-awk-or-other#comment28253870_19108173) this might work for you:

```
awk '{FS=OFS="\t"} $7=$7 FS $116 FS $119 FS $121 FS $124 FS $127 FS $129 FS $131 FS $134 FS $137 FS $140 FS $143 FS $146 FS $149 FS $152 FS $155 FS $158' inputfile
```

EDIT: If you have a header, you could say:

```
awk 'NR>1 {FS=OFS="\t"} $7=$7 FS $116 FS $119 FS $121 FS $124 FS $127 FS $129 FS $131 FS $134 FS $137 FS $140 FS $143 FS $146 FS $149 FS $152 FS $155 FS $158' inputfile
```

Comment: This would be a copy and not move,  `$116 $119`, is printed double.

Comment: @Jotne No, it won't delete `$116 $119 ...`.  Those would be *inserted* after the 7th column.

Comment: OP request it to move, remove original position, see comment my post.

Comment: @Jotne I'm not so sure.  Both the comment and the sample data in the question don't seem to suggest so *to me*.

Comment: Wow - thanks for all the help.  This one by devnull is real close.  It is copying those columns and putting them in the right place.  I don't care if they get deleted where they were.  But - it is messing up my header line.  Basically, it is tunring all the spaces in my column headers into tabs.

Comment: @devnull You seems to be correct from the comment above.  It could be more clear in the request.

Comment: @user1265669 You didn't tell that you had a header, see edit.

Comment: @Jotne When OP isn't quite clear (as in the current case), people might have their own interpretations of the issue.  Too much of commenting/downvoting other posts in such cases might be unwarranted.

Answer (score 0):

This one moves the fields vs. just copying, but cannot have empty fields.
Without having to iterate over the 1-NF, you can append the fields to $1 and remove them by setting them to "", but you'd have double tabs in the "holes".  Fortunately these can be removed with `tr` assuming you don't have any empty fields to begin with.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
{
  $7=$7"\t"$116"\t"$119"\t"$121"\t"$124"\t"$127"\t"$129"\t"$131"\t"$134"\t"$137"\t"$140"\t"$143"\t"$146"\t"$149"\t"$152"\t"$155"\t"$158
  $116=$119=$121=$124=$127=$129=$131=$134=$137=$140=$143=$146=$149=$152=$155=$158=""
  print
}' infile | tr -s "\t" >outfile
```